# Undefined is not a function (near '...(0,_reactNavigation.StackNavigator)...')

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I'm doing a study project (Weather application) in react native. I'm using react-navigation v4. It gives the above mentioned error. Please anybody help to resolve this.

```
//Index.js

import React from "react";
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducer from "./reducers";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import WeatherDetails from './screens/WeatherDetails';
import CityLists from './screens/CityLists';

const Navigation = StackNavigator({
  WeatherDetails: { screen: WeatherDetails },
  CityLists: { screen: CityLists }
});

const store = createStore(reducer, applyMiddleware(thunk));

const wrapper = () => {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Navigation />
    </Provider>
  );
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => wrapper);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [react-navigationv(4.0) documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html) you have to install `StackNavigator` separately. So first install `StackNavigator` :

> npm install react-navigation-stack --save

Then import `createStackNavigator` from `react-navigation-stack` :

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Now, create navigation :

```js
const Navigation = createStackNavigator ({
  WeatherDetails: { screen: WeatherDetails },
  CityLists: { screen: CityLists }
});
```

Comment: I did it and wrapped the navigation with AppContainer as mentioned in the document. But this time I'm getting new error that AppContainer is not a function

Comment: I solved it that was my mistake. createAppContainer is from react-navigation. I imported that from react-navigation-stack. Thanks for the help.